# retrieve from all row and display it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM main";

    if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $name= $row["name"];
            $image = $row["image"];


        }

    }
```

then somewhere in my code I print it out using like echo $name; but I got only one result, which is the last row. I know I have to do foreach but what variable should I put?

`foreach($result as $results)` ? like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every iteration, you reassign the values to `$name` and `$image`, causing it to show only the last value when it leaves the loop.

You can either echo them right away in the loop, or populate an array or an object with them, so they will be available later.

Example:

```
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = array('name'=>$row["name"], 'image'=>$row["image"]); // push into the array
}

var_dump($data); // it's all here now
```

And to echo the data later, one of the ways is foreach:

```
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "Name: ", $row['name'], "; Image: ", $row['image];
}
```

Comment: so I have to put them within a foreach loop? I've seen that kind of logic but in my case what's wrong? the sql or missing of a foreach loop to print the variable?

Comment: @user3522892 The SQL is correct for fetching all rows.

Comment: @user3522892: Well, you already *have* a loop. If you want to output the values right there, then output them *within that loop*. If you want to store them for later, then you need to store them in an array of some kind.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson is it correct? you sound oppose to Shomz suggest.

Comment: Joachim and I are saying the same thing - your SQL is good, you just need to keep the data once you're out of the loop. I didn't put the query in my answer, only the `while` part.

Comment: @Shomz thx for the answer, but why don't we loop during the echo of the variable part? won't it be more readable?

Comment: @Shomz how can u echo such data then?

Comment: Later you can do whatever you want with it, including the loop. I just showed you the way to keep your data for later use.

Comment: @Shomz Khrisna posted a more clear answer. (at least it's easier for me to understand)

Comment: Khrishna posted what I said in the 2nd row of my answer: `You can either echo them right away in the loop`... As I said a few times already, I taught you to **keep the data when you leave the loop**. In your example, it's the same as your query result (if you only have columns `name` and `image` in your table), but more often than not you'll need only pieces of data, so no need to carry the whole result object around (imagine you had 15 columns in your table, and you still had to do `SELECT *` for some reason). And it's much easier to manipulate it once it's in the array or object format.

Comment: @Shomz I tried your code above, it work. but I have 3 row it gave me 2 instead, missing the first one. Anything u missed?

Comment: Nope, my code has nothing to do with the number of rows.

Comment: @Shomz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26086750/retrieve-all-row-but-the-first-record-is-missing

Comment: You never said you had that `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` in front of the while loop. I can't guess your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM main";

$result = $db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

foreach ($row as $rows) {
  echo $rows['name'] ." ". $rows['image'];
}
```