# Retrieve all row but the first record is missing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM abc";

    if ($result = $db->query($query)) {

      $row = $result->fetch_assoc();


        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $data[] = array("a"=>$row["a"], 
                            "b"=>$row["b"],
                            "c"=>$row["c"],
                            "d"=>$row["d"]
                            ); 


        }

        $result->close();
    }

$db->close();

        <?php foreach ($data as $row) { ?>

                <form action="">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['a'] ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['b'] ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['c'] ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['d'] ?>"/>
                    </div>
                </form>

              <?php } ?>
```

Above is the exact code that I used to retrieve all the row in a table. The strange part is that I have 5 row and it only show 4. The first row is missing. I wonder why.

Comment: You are calling `fetch_assoc()` before the `while` loop.  That is eating the first record.  This question pops up rather frequently.  Is there some coding template somewhere that has this problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff coding template? so any solution to that eating part?

Comment: Just remove the extra call before the `while` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you're calling `$row = $result->fetch_assoc();` just before starting your `while` loop. This line is "consuming" your first raw and when you're entering in the loop, you move the cursor to the second row by calling this same method a second time.

The condition of the `while` loop is executed BEFORE the content, here you'll find more info about [PHP While loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

To fix your code, remove this first line.

Comment: omg how careless am I, didn't notice that! thx for pointing that out!